# Why is TLP a command not found?

Tags: debian-based

Running Debian 10 on a MacbookPro9,2 (mid 2012).

I downloaded the tlp packages as I was supposed to (with buster backports), everything went fine.`tlp-stat` (included in the installation) works. `tlp-rdw` (also included) also works. **`tlp` alone doesn't, it says to me that the command hasn't been found.** The strange thing is that `man tlp` gives me its manual page, so... anybody knows how to help?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, had to use

```
sudo tlp [COMMAND]
```

If your user doesn't have root access you may need to switch user with su